# Unable to start a project with Gatsby+Ghost

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, ghost-blog

I'm new with Gatsby and I am trying to start a project based on **Gatsby + Ghost** but I can solve this problem that appears right away I execute the command from the [official github page](https://github.com/tryghost/gatsby-starter-ghost):

```
$ gatsby new gatsby-starter-ghost https://github.com/TryGhost/gatsby-starter-ghost.git
```

```
info Creating new site from git: https://github.com/TryGhost/gatsby-starter-ghost.git

Cloning into 'gatsby-starter-ghost'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 80, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (80/80), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (67/67), done.
remote: Total 80 (delta 2), reused 42 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
success Created starter directory layout
info Installing packages...

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: gatsby-starter-ghost@2.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.9.0" from @tryghost/helpers-gatsby@1.0.50
npm ERR! node_modules/@tryghost/helpers-gatsby
npm ERR!   @tryghost/helpers-gatsby@"1.0.50" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /Users/mabvmex/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

 ERROR

Command failed with exit code 1: npm install


  Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm install
```

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As it is prompted:

```
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.2" from the root project

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.9.0" from @tryghost/helpers-gatsby@1.0.50
npm ERR! node_modules/@tryghost/helpers-gatsby
npm ERR!   @tryghost/helpers-gatsby@"1.0.50" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
```

You are running React `v17.0.2` which it's a major upgrade from the required React version (`^16.9.0`). You should be able to run your project with your current version of React but you may need to install the peer dependencies by:

```
npm install gatsby@latest --legacy-peer-deps
```

Note: remove the `package-lock`, your `node_modules` and potentially your `.cache` folder before running it.

Comment: Thanks... So I have the project directory. On it I install the --legacy-peer-deps and THEN the gatsby+ghost command?

Comment: First install Gatsby (latest version with legacy peer dependencies) and then run the starter command

Comment: The issue continues... I modified the package.json from the "broken" installation and change the react version.